# XOR on char does not work on groovy

Tags: groovy, xor

Why this does not work with groovy?

```
  ('a' as char) ^ ('b' as char)​
```

It raises

```
  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Character.xor() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Character) values: [b]
  Possible solutions: div(java.lang.Character), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), plus(java.lang.Character), is(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2)
```

As far as i know it breaks compatible source with java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works with Groovy 1.8.4:

```
println( ('a' as char) ^ ('b' as char) )
```

prints

```
3
```

Groovy has quite a few places where the source is incompatible from Java.  A [list can be found here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java), there are also things like no `do...while` loop, etc...

#### Edit

Jochen Theodorou, the Groovy Project Tech Lead [replied to the mail on the list](http://markmail.org/message/v3qkf3grpgxlh3jf):

> the currently "right" way is
>
> println(  ('a'  as  int)  ^  ('b'  as  int)  )
>
> and it should still print 3. As of why it works sometimes and
> sometimes not... I think that is because I accidentally implemented
> that for the primitive optimizations. That means you get this in later
> 1.8 versions, because before it was not implemented. And it means it works only if they are enabled, which is the case in only specific
> situations.

#### Edit #2

This is looking like an issue that only shows itself with certain implementations of the JVM.  As such, [I have posted an issue to the Groovy Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5189), so hopefully future versions of Groovy will smooth out the differences a bit :-)

Comment: well for me it does not, on ubuntu, groovy 1.8.4 JVM: 1.6.0_23

Comment: @fixitagain Bizarre...  works with OS X Groovy Version: 1.8.4 JVM: 1.6.0_26 I'll ask on the mailing list

Comment: @fixitagain Fingers crossed [someone can work out what's going on](http://groovy.markmail.org/thread/keyqmeyfdztgzfxz)...

Comment: thanks, i think i hit some kind of side bug, like `^` or `as char` being misprocessed on some platforms

Comment: actually, i made some tests and `println 0x0001*('a' as char)^('b' as char)*0x0001` works! or even `println 1*('a' as char)^('b' as char)*1` but sounds the bit operation is made with integer. You can find it out when you remove the `1*`, it raises an error involving java.lang.Integer.

Comment: @fixitagain Added the reply from Jochen to my answer

Comment: @fixitagain Just to make sure you're definately on `1.8.4`, can you run `println GroovySystem.version ; println( ('a' as char) ^ ('b' as char) )` ... Does that print `1.8.4` followed by the exception?

Comment: well the solution of Jochen does not work neither on my machine nor in webconsole. try it out! and `GroovySystem.version` gives me `1.8.4`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5816/discussion-between-fixitagain-and-tim-yates)